# I want to start limiting the item slots and then update the extend slot by pressing M

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inventory

I have completed the inventory slots already and want to lock and unlock some slots for extending after ....(which press m for testing)

I press M and unlock slot increasing now but cannot use extended slots after  increase the number of unlock slot.

Have completed all inventory slots and item to move among slots

```cs
public abstract class ItemContainer : MonoBehaviour, IItemContainer
{
    public List<ItemSlot> ItemSlots;

    public int unlockSlot = 1;

    public event Action<BaseItemSlot> OnPointerEnterEvent;
    public event Action<BaseItemSlot> OnPointerExitEvent;
    public event Action<BaseItemSlot> OnRightClickEvent;
    public event Action<BaseItemSlot> OnBeginDragEvent;
    public event Action<BaseItemSlot> OnEndDragEvent;
    public event Action<BaseItemSlot> OnDragEvent;
    public event Action<BaseItemSlot> OnDropEvent;

    protected virtual void OnValidate()
    {
        GetComponentsInChildren(includeInactive: true, result: ItemSlots);
    }

    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ItemSlots.Count/5* unlockSlot; i++)
        {
            ItemSlots[i].OnPointerEnterEvent += slot => EventHelper(slot, OnPointerEnterEvent);
            ItemSlots[i].OnPointerExitEvent += slot => EventHelper(slot, OnPointerExitEvent);
            ItemSlots[i].OnRightClickEvent += slot => EventHelper(slot, OnRightClickEvent);
            ItemSlots[i].OnBeginDragEvent += slot => EventHelper(slot, OnBeginDragEvent);
            ItemSlots[i].OnEndDragEvent += slot => EventHelper(slot, OnEndDragEvent);
            ItemSlots[i].OnDragEvent += slot => EventHelper(slot, OnDragEvent);
            ItemSlots[i].OnDropEvent += slot => EventHelper(slot, OnDropEvent);
        }
    }

    private void EventHelper(BaseItemSlot itemSlot, Action<BaseItemSlot> action)
    {
        if (action != null)
            action(itemSlot);
    }

    public virtual bool CanAddItem(Item item, int amount = 1)
    {
        int freeSpaces = 0;

        foreach (ItemSlot itemSlot in ItemSlots)
        {
            if (itemSlot.Item == null || itemSlot.Item.ID == item.ID)
            {
                freeSpaces += item.MaxStacks - itemSlot.Amount;
            }
        }
        return freeSpaces >= amount;
    }

    public virtual bool AddItem(Item item)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ItemSlots.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ItemSlots[i].CanAddStack(item))
            {
                ItemSlots[i].Item = item;             
                ItemSlots[i].Amount++;               
                return true;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ItemSlots.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ItemSlots[i].Item == null)
            {
                if (item.ID == item.ID)
                {
                    ItemSlots[i].Item = item;
                    ItemSlots[i].Amount++;
                    return true;
                }

            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public virtual bool RemoveItem(Item item)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ItemSlots.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ItemSlots[i].Item == item)
            {
                ItemSlots[i].Amount--;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public virtual Item RemoveItem(string itemID)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ItemSlots.Count; i++)
        {
            Item item = ItemSlots[i].Item;
            if (item != null && item.ID == itemID)
            {
                ItemSlots[i].Amount--;
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public virtual int ItemCount(string itemID)
    {
        int number = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < ItemSlots.Count; i++)
        {
            Item item = ItemSlots[i].Item;
            if (item != null && item.ID == itemID)
            {
                number += ItemSlots[i].Amount;
            }
        }
        return number;
    }


    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.M))
        {
            unlockSlot++;
            Debug.Log(unlockSlot);
        }
    }
}
```

unlock slot not increase (debug not showing) and the rest slots disable to use

Comment: Fixed: just duplicate start function to fixedupdate.

Answer (score 0):

> Fixed: just duplicate start function to fixedupdate.

**DON'T!**

1. This sounds very bad for resources ... why setting this all the time? Rather move it to the moment in which you actually change `unlockSlot` and do it there only **once**.
2. Additionally you do `+=` with a lambda expression. So the events will be added additional incremental so next time the callback is executed twice .. then 3 times etc.
   And since it is a lambda expression you also can't use `-=` in order to remove the callback.

In order to automatize it a bit I would use a [property with backing field](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) like

```
private int unlockSlot = 1;
public int UnlockSlot
{
    get
    {
        return unlockSlot;
    }
    // you can additionally make the setter private so only this class
    // can change the value while other classes have only read permissions
    /*private*/
    set
    {
        unlockSlot = value;

        UpdateItemSlots();
    }
}
```

Then you can avoid your `EventHelper` .. this can simply be written as

```
private void UpdateItemSlots()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < ItemSlots.Count / 5 * unlockSlot; i++)
    {
        // Before adding callbacks remove them
        // this is valid even if they were not added before
        // but makes sure they are added only exactly once
        ItemSlots[i].OnPointerEnterEvent -= OnPointerEnterEvent;
        ItemSlots[i].OnPointerExitEvent -= OnPointerExitEvent;
        ItemSlots[i].OnRightClickEvent -= OnRightClickEvent;
        ItemSlots[i].OnBeginDragEvent -= OnBeginDragEvent;
        ItemSlots[i].OnEndDragEvent -= OnEndDragEvent;
        ItemSlots[i].OnDragEvent -= OnDragEvent;
        ItemSlots[i].OnDropEvent -= OnDropEvent;

        // add your callback events .. no need for this complex lambda construct
        ItemSlots[i].OnPointerEnterEvent += OnPointerEnterEvent;
        ItemSlots[i].OnPointerExitEvent += OnPointerExitEvent;
        ItemSlots[i].OnRightClickEvent += OnRightClickEvent;
        ItemSlots[i].OnBeginDragEvent += OnBeginDragEvent;
        ItemSlots[i].OnEndDragEvent += OnEndDragEvent;
        ItemSlots[i].OnDragEvent += OnDragEvent;
        ItemSlots[i].OnDropEvent += OnDropEvent;
    }
}
```

Afaik you don't need the `null` check for `event Action` you could go for sure and declare them in a way they are never null like e.g.

```
public event Action<BaseItemSlot> OnPointerEnterEvent = slot => {};
```

this adds an empty callback which is as said before not removable due to being a lambda expression => it is assured that `OnPointerEnterEvent` will never be `null`.

Now simply change

```
protected virtual void Start()
{
    UpdateItemSlots();
}
```

and remember to not use `unlockSlot` but rather `UnlockSlot` for changing its value so also the slots get updated automatically by the property

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.M))
    {
        UnlockSlot++;
        // for reading in this case it doesn't matter
        // but for being consequent I would also use the property here
        Debug.Log(UnlockSlot);
    }
}
```